# How should I link WCF/SOA requests and responses in a MS HPC job?

Tags: .net, wcf, soa, hpc

I'm trying to create a simple WCF/SOA application for a HPC cluster, and I'm not sure if HPC provides or not a way to link a SOA response to the task that generated it.

Following a tutorial I got, I created code that submits tasks to the cluster like this:

```
using (var proxy = new BrokerClient<WcfMathService.IMath>(session, binding)){
...
proxy.SetResponseHandler<WcfMathService.RunTaskResponse>(doSubmit_ServiceCallback, m_signal);
...
proxy.SendRequest(new WcfMathService.RunTaskRequest(i, args.taskTime, args.taskFailureChance));
```

It would be useful when using SendRequest to get immediately the task id, but I have no clue where to get it from, BrokerClient doesn't seem to know.

Later on, on my callback code, I can get an array on ints that I returned from the service task:
    int[] r = response.Result.RunTaskResult;

But again, from the response I have no idea how to guess the task that generated it. I could pass an identifier with the request and then pass it back again in the results array, but that is not very elegant and has the problem that if the task crashes with an unhandled exception, I don't know which task was that failed.

I'm quite puzzled on how to do proper task management with HPC cluster, I have to admit.